# How do I uninstall/purge php 7.x completely? (Kali/Debian)

Tags: kali-linux, php, uninstall

On my distribution of Kali (2016.2) there was a php package v7.0.11 preinstalled. I'd like to use version 5.6 instead. Could anyone guide me through on how to remove it? I've already tried, looking for some guides online, but php7 is still pretty fresh, so there are not too many threads about it, especially while using Kali. Nevertheless, I found some clues but I didn't manage to do it properly, apparently. A lot of mess with dependencies, and overall, my whole Kali install is now broken.

After purging php7, I'd like to install php 5.6, is there an easy way to do it with apt?

P.S. This was previously posted on Stack Overflow. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you're having sort of the same problem that I had when I tried to do the same with Apache2. Here's how to purge it and remove it.
 First, enter.
`service --status-all` 
 To see the exact name of it, just find it in the list. 
Next, type 
`apt-get --purge nameofprogramyouwanttopurge` 
 **DO NOT CONTINUE UNTIL YOU READ THIS NEXT PART THROUGH** Now, when that command initializes, it will give you the option of (y,n) and you choose yes or no. Before you choose yes or no, fully read the entire output in your terminal and make sure of every file it is preparing to remove is what you want to remove. Don't hit yes until you are sure there's no packages or dependencies being purged that you don't want purged. Don't be lazy and skip the reading.
 If you are satisfied with all the files it lists being purged, then select yes And move to the next step. 
 After the purging and removal is done, you will want to enter
 `apt-get upgrade` 
 Reply back here with the output of that line before you say yes to the upgrade.